# parse a yml file which has . in key using shyaml

Tags: yaml

I have the following yaml file -

```
ex1:
  name: abcd
ex.2:
  name: xyz
```

When I trying doing -

`cat a.yml| shyaml get-value ex.2.name`

It throws an error -

`Error: invalid path 'ex.2.name', missing key 'ex' in struct.`

I tried escaping the . using \ but couldn't get it to work. Is there a way I can parse this yaml file? I would like to avoid writing shell scripts for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the key in single quotes, that fixed it for me.

```
cat a.yml| shyaml get-value 'ex\.2.name'
```